# How to transition from a preview image to the full size in a table. (onmouseover="this.width=MAX WIDTH;this.height=MAX HEIGHT")

Tags: html, css, image

### I'm making a photo gallery and need to be able to use the same code for each image. However not all images are the same size. I've set the preview windows (each table block) at 275px by 200px. I'm wondering if there's some code that will allow me to enlarge the image to it's native size (not proportional to 275px by 200px) so that the code will apply cleanly to every image. I already tried putting 100% but that doesn't work.

edit: @AjayMalhotra   @IamL   @MisterEpic

here is a more clear, example of the html with working image examples. I tried all of the answers and none worked. They either made the image disappear, flicker or do nothing. To clarify, I am trying to, on mouse hover, have the table unit expand to the size of the picture automatically. I know it's kind of weird it might not even be do-able. Thanks again for your help!

```
    <table cellpadding="0" border="0">  
        <tr>
            <td width="275px" height="200px" onmouseover="width='586px'; height='440px'" style="background-repeat:no-repeat" 
            class="fx" onmouseleave="width='275px'; height='200px'" align="center" background="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/72c/danger-school-traffic-signal-1444922.jpg"></td>

            <td width="275px" height="200px" onmouseover="width='410px'; height='615px'" style="background-repeat:no-repeat" 
            class="fx" onmouseleave="width='275px'; height='200px'" align="center" background="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/20000/nahled/business-time-11291126308C1Y.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I need to clarify, you ate trying to hover the table. Then expand THE CELL(NOT THE PICTURE) to the size of the picture. Am i right?

Comment: Yeah. So that the full picture is shown. The cell acts as a sort of preview window. It already works it's just that I need to manually input the full picture dimensions and for a gallery I can't go do that one by one it would take way to long

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to enlarge when your mouse cursor is over the image:

```
img{
  width:275px;
  height:200px;
}

img:hover{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yfnzo8te/

Comment: could you take a look at the edits to the question and see if you can help me figure it out? the width:auto just made the image flicker when I tried to integrate it into my own code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this on your css.
if you are going to resize the background image:

```
td:hover {
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

If you are going to resize an image inside the td.

```
td:hover img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You may also try adding max-width and max-height if you want:

```
td:hover img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I edited the question maybe it'll be a bit more clear. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

No need to call javascript for small tasks.

I think this snippet will help you :

```css
.grid-img:hover{position:absolute;width:100%;height:auto;
transition: width .3s;-webkit-transition: width .3s;-moz-transition: width .5s;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
   <tr>
      <td width="275px">
     <img class="grid-img"  width="275px" height="200px" src="http://www.medhatspca.ca/sites/default/files/news_photos/2014-Apr-15/node-147/cute-little-cat.jpg">
     </td>
     <td>
       sadasDSadASDSAdaS
     </td>
     <td>
       sadasDSadASDSAdaS
     </td>
     <td>
       sadasDSadASDSAdaS
     </td>
     <td>
       sadasDSadASDSAdaS
     </td>
     <td>
       sadasDSadASDSAdaS
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If this is not the answer you want then please explain me properly. Surly I will find some solution.

Comment: I edited the question maybe it'll be a bit more clear. Thank you for helping!